# ionic fail to load plugin throw the installation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have an app made with ionic I got this error when I install a plugin

```
core.js:1449 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at AppRate.set [as preferences] (index.js:31)
    at MyApp.webpackJsonp.259.MyApp.initializeApp (app.component.ts:32)
    at new MyApp (app.component.ts:19)
    at createClass (core.js:12491)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12326)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13784)
    at createRootView (core.js:13673)
    at Object.createProdRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14366)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11278)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4030)
```

in my case I try to add AppRate plugin, I added the plugin in app.modle.ts and app.componets.ts like the code shown below

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate/ngx';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = 'MenuPage';


  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private appRate: AppRate) {
    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });

    // or, override the whole preferences object
  this.appRate.preferences = {
    usesUntilPrompt: 3,
    storeAppURL: {
    ios: '<app_id>',
    android: 'market://details?id=<package_name>',
    windows: 'ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=<store_id>'
    }
  }

this.appRate.promptForRating(false);
  }
}
enableProdMode();
```

I use the ionic framework documentation to install the plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apprate
npm install @ionic-native/app-rate
```

and I got this WARN at the installation processes

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/app-rate@5.3.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/app-rate@5.3.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself
```

I do re-installed node.js, npm and ionic cordova from my mac and still have the same problem, I'm using ionic4 on mac os Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade your app rate plugin version like that :

```
nom install @ionic-native/app-rate@4.3.1
```

The version of your plugin is too high  (ionic 5).